# break function for shouldoverrideurlloading?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using **shouldoverrideurlloading** to trigger a function when a link is clicked in my webview. Is their a way to stop the webview from loading a new screen when the link is clicked. All I want to do is run the function `NetworkOperations.addlike(url)` when a user clicks the link not load a new page in webview

EX:

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {

            if (url.endsWith("&like"))
            {

                NetworkOperations.addlike(url);
                Break;

            }
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return `true` it should NOT load the url in the `WebView`, while `false` will let the `WebView` load the page.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (url.endsWith("&like")) {
    NetworkOperations.addlike(url);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)